# chatbot interrupts conversation

Tags: python, rasa

I’m creating a chatbot a bit different from what we are used to use and I need help and advice. The idea is that the chatbot has an external interface as I have read that for the bot to start the conversation is necessary (correct me if it is not true), the problem is that I have never created an interface like this and when I have tried to take created projects and test them to see how it would look like I can not get it to work, I attach an example of how it looks once written rasa.

Example of a conversation:

```
(11:22) User:Hello
(11:22) Bot: Hello, how can I help you?
(11:23) User: What will the weather be like today?
(11:23) Bot: It will rain this afternoon.
(Stands by on hold)
(14:12) Bot: It's already raining.
(14:13) User: Will it rain for a long time?
(14:13) Bot: Yes, it will be raining for about three hours
```

I know how to do the first part, until the bot takes the initiative, but I don't know how to continue.

index.html:

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <script>!(function () {
        let e = document.createElement("script"),
          t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (e.src =
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@1.0.0/lib/index.js"),
          // Replace 1.x.x with the version that you want
          (e.async = !0),
          (e.onload = () => {
            window.WebChat.default(
              {
                initPayload: '/greet',
                customData: { language: "en" },
                socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
                // add other props here
              },
              null
            );
          }),
          t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
      })();
      </script>      
    </body>    
</html>
```

credentials.yml:

```
# This file contains the credentials for the voice & chat platforms
# which your bot is using.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/messaging-and-voice-channels

rest:
#  # you don't need to provide anything here - this channel doesn't
#  # require any credentials


#facebook:
#  verify: "<verify>"
#  secret: "<your secret>"
#  page-access-token: "<your page access token>"

#slack:
#  slack_token: "<your slack token>"
#  slack_channel: "<the slack channel>"
#  slack_signing_secret: "<your slack signing secret>"

socketio:
  user_message_evt: user_uttered
  bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
  session_persistence: true

#mattermost:
#  url: "https://<mattermost instance>/api/v4"
#  token: "<bot token>"
#  webhook_url: "<callback URL>"

# This entry is needed if you are using Rasa X. The entry represents credentials
# for the Rasa X "channel", i.e. Talk to your bot and Share with guest testers.
rasa:
  url: "http://localhost:5002/api"
```

**I have several questions:**

1. Why if I type rasa shell the chatbot works correctly but if I type `rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug` and open `index.html` I get a blank.
   [enter image description here][1]
2. How to make the second part even to test it with rasa shell?
3. Can you start the bot in different ways, for example, *It is starting to rain* and other times: *It has stopped snowing*?

Any ideas, suggestions, pages that can help me?

Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shcz0.png

Answer (score 1):

> Why if I type rasa shell the chatbot works correctly but if I type
> rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug and open index.html
> I get a blank. [enter image description here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#chat-widget)

I suggest using the official [rasa chat widget](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/your-own-website/#chat-widget) as your frontend. If you have questions about it you can ask it in the [rasa forum](https://forum.rasa.com/). If you found a bug, you can file a bug report in the [rasa open source repo](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa).

> How to make the second part even to test it with rasa shell?

This documentation on [how to get the bot to start the conversation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reaching-out-to-user/#reaching-out-first) with the user should help you get started.

> Can you start the bot in different ways, for example, It is starting
> to rain and other times: It has stopped snowing?

You can send to the bot the trigger intent that will trigger the desired response from the bot. See answer to the question for details.